# ¿Calcular el promedio en minutos?

Tags: laravel, foreach, carbon

estoy tratando de calcular el promedio de tiempo entre la columna created_at y updated_at, pero estoy teniendo problemas con el foreach, ya que solo toma el ultimo valor que le envío, e ignora todos los demás.

```
public function tiempo()
{
    $creaciones = Deposito::where('autorizacion','=','1')->get();
    $prome= count($creaciones);
    foreach($creaciones as $creacion)
    {
        $timein = $creacion->created_at;
        $timefn = $creacion->updated_at;
        $dif = $timein->diffInMinutes($timefn); 
        $suma = $dif;
        $pro = (int)$suma;
        $tiempo = $pro/$prome;  
    } 
    return view('graficas.sucursales',compact('tiempo'));   
}
```

Me podrían decir que debo hacer para que recorra todos los resultados de la consulta.

Comment: Te refieres a que el promedio que te sale es igual al ultimo valor dividido el total de registros?

Comment: exacto, el ultimo registro tiene una diferencia de 23 minutos, eso lo divide entre el total de registros.no hace la suma del total de minutos de todos los registros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el promedio debes de calcularlo fuera del `foreach`.  Ademas no estas sumando todos los valores.  Seria algo asi:

```
public function tiempo()
{
    $creaciones = Deposito::where('autorizacion','=','1')->get();
    $prome= count($creaciones);
    $suma = 0;
    foreach($creaciones as $creacion)
    {
        $timein = $creacion->created_at;
        $timefn = $creacion->updated_at;
        $dif = $timein->diffInMinutes($timefn); 
        $suma += $dif;            
    }
    $pro = (int)$suma;
    $tiempo = $pro/$prome;  
    return view('graficas.sucursales',compact('tiempo'));   
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, a funcionado perfectamente. También edite el código para hacerlo más fácil de entender. El tuyo funciona perfectamente, solo le di un nombre mas sencillo de entender a las variables. Publico el código?